# Passing variables inside jenkins pipeline closure body

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a pipeline function to retry stages 3 times:

```
def restart(body){
    retry(3){
        body()
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
def prepareStage(accountName, slave_tag) {
    return {
        restart(){
            node(slave_tag){
                stage("${target} ${accountName}") {
                    build job: "pipelines/${accountName}/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but now I wanted to pass another variable "retries" to decide whether it should retry 3 times or not, something like this:

```
def restart(body, retries){
    if (retries == false){
        body()
    }
    else {
        retry(3){
            body()
        }
    }
}

def prepareStage(accountName, slave_tag, retries) {
    return {
        restart(retries){
            node(slave_tag){
                stage("${target} ${accountName}") {
                    build job: "pipelines/${accountName}/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting "no such DSL method restart"

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error message you're getting, but I noticed another bug. You need to change the order of your input arguments to `restart`. `retries` should be first and `body` should be second, based on the way you call the function.

Comment: it's solved, thanks @Vasiliki Siakka. I just had to invert to this "def restart(retries, body)"

Answer (score 1):

It's solved thanks to @Vasiliki Siakka comment:

```
def restart(retries, body){
    if (retries == false){
        body()
    }
    else {
        retry(3){
            body()
        }
    }
}

def prepareStage(accountName, slave_tag, retries) {
    return {
        restart(retries){
            node(slave_tag){
                stage("${target} ${accountName}") {
                    build job: "pipelines/${accountName}/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```